# Recursive integer partitioning algorithm

Tags: scala, partitioning

I am trying to count in how many ways I can partition an integer. So far I came up with the following function:

```
def partition(num: Int): Int = {
    if(num == 1) return 1
    if(num <= 0) return 0
    return partition(num-1) + partition(num-(num-1))
}
partition(6) //6 instead of 7
```

E.g.: `5 -> 4 + 1, 3 + 2, 2 + 2 + 1, 2 + 1 + 1 + 1, 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1`

It returns 1 if `num` is 1 because I think `partition(1)` is the end.

Maybe you can spot the logic error in it?

Comment: If "1" is a valid partition of 1, shouldn't then "5" also be a valid partition of 5?

Comment: @mhs the idea behind it is that it should return 1 when it reaches the `partition(1)` point.

Comment: Also `num-(num-1) == 1`. This seems wrong whatever you are trying to achieve (which is not stated clearly).

Comment: @ziggystar right, I edited it :)

Comment: Do you account for permutations?

Comment: Not sure about the algo, but your test case is wrong: 5 -> 3 + 2, 4 + 1, 2 + 2 + 1, 3 + 1 + 1, 2 + 1 + 1 + 1, 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1, which is 6... Also partition(6) should be 10 (if you don't include 6 itself). You probably need an extra argument to keep track of valid ints that can make up the partition so that you can break the problem in two.

Comment: The example for 5 is missing the partition 3+1+1.

Comment: Wikipedia is listing 11 for partition(6), neither 6 nor 7.

Answer (score 4):

I think this works:

```
def partition(n: Int): Int = {
  def inner(n: Int, max: Int): Int =
    if (n == 0) 1
    else if (n < 0) 0
    else ((1 to max) map (x => inner(n - x, x))).sum

  if (n == 0) 0
  else inner(n, n-1)
}
```

An integer `n` can be partitioned into `(n-1) + (any way of partitioning 1)`, `(n-2) + (any way of partitioning 2)`, ..., `1 + (any way of partitioning (n-1))`. However, naïvely computing `partition(m)` for `m = 1 to n-1` and summing the results will count some methods of partitioning `n` twice, e.g. `1 + (n-1)` and `(n-1) + 1`.

We can solve this problem by viewing a partition as a sequence of positive integers `i{j} < n` that sum to `n`, and only considering sequences that are *ordered*. The `inner` method has a `max` parameter that ensures it will only consider sequences with `i{j} >= i{j+1}`. So it will consider e.g. `2 + 1`, but not `1 + 2`.

`n == 0` is an annoying edge case in the above code because you effectively don't want to count the empty sequence.

Comment: I think usually 0 has 1 partition, the empty sequence, so you can drop that if.

Comment: Also your solution is off by 1 regarding the usual number theoretic definition, probably because of the example given which does not list 5 as a partition of 5.

Answer (score 2):

```
def partition(n: Int): Int = {
    def partDecr(n: Int, decr: Int): Int = {
        if (n == 0) 1
        else if (n < 0 || decr == 0) 0
        else partDecr(n - decr, decr) + partDecr(n, decr - 1)
    }
    partDecr(n, n)
}
```

- The inner function takes an extra parameter specifying the next possible decrement.
- First it checks if we are at a valid end point (1 solution found).
- Then it checks if we can go on (positive rest to partition, and positive decrement to try next).
- Then it recurses into 2 ways:

  - The first "takes" the current decrement and reduces n by it,
  - The second "skips" the current decrement and will try with the next lower one.

Note this is not tail recursive and can use quite some stack space, but it is so slow it doesn't matter much.

Comment: Isn't it the same as my answer posted 8 hours before? (as well as my comments under the question)? Or you are not seeing http://stackoverflow.com/a/12642881/257449 when you check the site? It's like you went through the same checks and thought process I went through but 8 hours later.

Comment: @huynhjl Yes comparing carefully, they are aequivalent algorithms. I didn't read past your madeOf=(...) line though, thinking you were using a list there. IMHO my code looks nicer, and I did not poach intentionally.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no "that simple" algorithm to compute what you want. The presented algorithm in the OP won't work for a couple of reasons (which I won't discuss).

But I direct you to the [Wikipedia entry on 'Partition'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29#Partition_function_formulas), which also includes a recursive formula.

Notice, that this exact formula is both computationally more complex and also more complicated than the presented algorithm in the OP.

Answer (score 1):

I think it requires another argument (the integers that can make up the partition, call it `madeOf`). That way you can divide the problem in 2 *strictly smaller* subsets. The count of `partition(num, madeOf=(n, n-1, ..., 1))` is the sum of

- `partition(num, madeOf=(n-1, ..., 1))` (all the partitions that don't contain n)
- `partition(num-n, madeOf(n, n-1, ..., 1))` (all the partitions where there is at least one n)

You can then make it more optimal, since `madeOf` can be constructed from only one int:

```
def part(num: Int, madeOf: Int): Int =
  if (num == 0) 1 // we found a partition!
  else if (num < 0) 0 // no partition...
  else if (madeOf == 0) 0 // no more ways to make partition
  else part(num, madeOf - 1) +  // all the partitions that don't contain n
    part(num - madeOf, madeOf)  // all the partition that contain n

part(5, 4) // 6
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following inner function - you only need to create a list with numbers < the number you want to partition. For example you want to partition 4, then intNumber should be (1,2,3,4)

```
  def partition(number: Int, intNumbers: List[Int]): Int = {    
if (number <= 0 || intNumbers.isEmpty) 
  0
else if ((number-intNumbers.head)==0) 
  1+partition(number-intNumbers.head,intNumbers)+partition(number,intNumbers.tail)
else 
  partition(number-intNumbers.head,intNumbers)+partition(number,intNumbers.tail)
```

Comment: What do I have to put into `intNumbers`? If `intNumbers` is always the range `1 to number` as in the example (but contradicting your description, since 4 < 4 is not true), why don't you compute it inside the function?

Comment: that is true. I just copied a similar part from my old code to demonstrate the logic. you can replace intNumbers